# outlook calendar events for rooms

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am making a web app which pulls the names and events of rooms from outlook calendar. I am able to get rooms list but how can I get the calendar schedule for each room. How would the get request look like then?

Here's the link of the tutorial that I used: [Build Node.js Express apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node)

Here's the link of the documentation of the room list: [user: findRooms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Please don't post code as images, it makes testing your code hard as it cannot be copy / pasted.

Answer (score 0):

The [getSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-beta) method get the free/busy availability information for a collection of users, distributions lists, or resources (rooms or equipment) for a specified time period.

`POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule`

If successful, this method returns a `200 OK` response code and a collection of [scheduleInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/scheduleinformation?view=graph-rest-beta) objects for each object in the schedules parameter.

It looks like the API is still in Beta and not yet supported in production applications. So, I'd suggest double check whether it works now in production or not.